Unable to get the sudo privileges
We have OpenLDAP servers, and all clients are working from many years. Now we are introducing Ubuntu 24.04, and LDAP user is able to login with his LDAP id. But unable to get the SUDO privileges.
ubuntu@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ sudo su - rvasamsetti
groups: cannot find name for group ID 41001
ubuntu@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ id rvasamsetti
uid=50489(rvasamsetti) gid=41001 groups=41001
ubuntu@ip-10-17-24-63:~$
ubuntu@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ sudo su - rvasamsetti
groups: cannot find name for group ID 41001
rvasamsetti@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ id
uid=50489(rvasamsetti) gid=41001 groups=41001
rvasamsetti@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ getent passwd rvasamsetti
rvasamsetti:x:50489:41001:Ramakrishna Venkata:/home/rvasamsetti:/bin/bash
rvasamsetti@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ getent group 41001
rvasamsetti@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ getent group tsuser
rvasamsetti@ip-10-17-24-63:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
[sudo] password for rvasamsetti:
rvasamsetti is not in the sudoers file.
rvasamsetti@ip-10-17-24-63:~$


This question is similar to: How can I add a user as a new sudoer using the command line?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
